# Python form login via mechanize

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to login to site via a form and mechanize with python, however after submitting the form it's still not logged in - i.e. after the br.submit() i'll try to grab a page using br.open('something') and I get the standard 'you are not logged in' message the site provides...code is below. Seeing anything incorrect?  I've tried altering/removing the headers with no luck...

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36')]

br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.open('http://www.marketbeat.com/login')

br.select_form(nr = 0)

br.form['ctl00$cphPrimaryContent$txtUserName'] = 'username@domain.com'
br.form['ctl00$cphPrimaryContent$txtPassword'] = 'password'

br.submit()
```

Comment: After submitting the page, fetch the response and print it.  Look for any error messages about mismatched password, invalid form, etc.

Comment: i did try that - it seems like when running the python script it is redirecting to a different page than when logging in thru the browser...i've tried changing the user-agent settings but so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

actually I figured it out - turns out there was javascript in the form and i had to use br.submit(name='whatever') to choose the right submission.